# Accessing NSArrayController's bound array from controlTextDidEndEditing delegate method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have an application that has a 23 column NSTableView. The NSTableView's content is bound to ArrayController.arrangedObjects in IB. In addition, each NSTextFieldCell contained within the table has value bound to Table Cell View objectValue.someKey. One of my columns has an editable value, so, I implemented the controlTextDidEndEditing delegate method. Another table column contains error text, and it is bound to objectValue.errorText.

The ArrayController mentioned above has a Content Array that is bound to an NSMutableArray, which is a property of my ViewController. This array contains a collection of "Event" objects, which are defined and validated when the application launches.

So the controlTextDidFinishEditing: method has a notification parameter, which in this case is the NSTextField that it was called from. What I would like to do in this method is access the underlying "Event" object, contained in the NSMutableArray that is bound to the ArrayController, and set the error text property of the "Event" object to @"".

I would imagine that this has a very simple answer, but I'm struggling trying to phrase my Google query correctly to yield the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: You can traverse the view hierarchy from the control up to the parent that has `objectValue`. Your `NSTextField` has a superview which is the `NSTableViewCell` containing the `objectValue` property.  You could get the edited field from the `userInfo` dictionary of the `aNotification` object, find which superview is a `NSTableViewCell`, and get to `objectValue` that way.   Rather than the delegate method, though, it might be more straightforward to get the view pointer with target-action, which would have `sender` rather than `aNotification`.

Comment: The other thing you can do is just override the `someKey` setter to set `errorText`.  Or have `errorText` as a dependent keypath of `someKey`, and override the `errorText` getter.  This is much cleaner than traversing the view hierarchy to achieve the same result.

Comment: @stevesliva I opted to use your first solution, since I wanted to make the Event class as generic as possible, and to have it not be implementation-specific. Here is what I came up with: `-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTextField *textField = [notification object];
    NSView* superView = [textField superview];
    Event* modifiedEvent = ((NSTableCellView*)superView).objectValue;
    [modifiedEvent setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [modifiedEvent setErrorMessage:@""];
    return;
}` Thank you SO much!

Comment: Glad it worked.   Wasn't sure whether it was the immediate superview, nor was I certain the best way to get the "sender" object from the notification.  I won't be offended if you write your own answer here with the code.

Comment: Alright @stevesliva, I'll do that. Thanks again, you're a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

This question already has an answer but if future readers want to know the bound object, they can inspect the binding of the textfield.

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTextField *textField = [aNotification object];
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [textField infoForBinding:NSValueBinding];
    NSTableCellView *tableCellView = [dictionary objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey];
    NSString *keyPath = [dictionary objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey];
    Event* modifiedEvent = tableCellView.objectValue;
    [modifiedEvent setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [modifiedEvent setErrorMessage:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from implementing @stevesliva's first suggestion.

I defined the controlTextDidEndEditing: method as follows.

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTextField *textField = [notification object];
    NSView* superView = [textField superview];
    Event* modifiedEvent = ((NSTableCellView*)superView).objectValue;
    [modifiedEvent setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [modifiedEvent setErrorMessage:@""];
    return;
}
```

The key here is to cast the return of superview as a NSTableCellView* object, instead of a generic NSView*. Doing so will allow you access to the objectValue property.